# Unable to validate SCIM endpoints using Microsoft SCIM validator

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, provisioning, scim

I have built the sign-on application based on Microsoft's provided sample SCIM code. I am trying to validate my endpoints using scimvalidator located at (https://scimvalidator.microsoft.com/) for Gallery app creation but always getting the below response without any other details:

```
Please confirm if token is valid and try again. SCIM Endpoints should respond with HTTP OK (200), and SCIM JSON with header application/scim+json.
```

[image]

The irony is same token works when used in Postman.

I am using the below endpoint to get the token and using the same token:

```
https://<host>/api/Token
```

And below is actual SCIM endpoint for users:

```
https://<host>/scim/Users
```

I have no clue to get more details about the actual error and there are not many resources available about SCIM validations.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

SCIM relies on a users and groups endpoint.

B2C does not [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/service-limits?pivots=b2c-user-flow#endpoint-request-usage) these.

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/isv-automatic-provisioning-multi-tenant-apps#choose-a-provisioning-method. Support non-enterprise accounts (B2C) = X (not supported)